# Linked tables using composite PK and FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a linked table. The two tables being linked are `Person` and `Address`. Both tables have a Primary Key of `ID`.

```
CREATE TABLE LinkedTable
(
   EntryID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
   PersonID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(ID),
   AddressID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Address(ID),
   PRIMARY KEY(EntryID, PersonID, AddressID)
)
```

Is it possible to set both Foreign Keys constraints and a composite Primary Key in a table script like this?

Comment: Have you tried? What happened?

Comment: @jarlh well to be honest, i don't have my computer with that has sql server on it so im not able to try at the moment

Comment: For a composite key, I believe that you'll need to add it as it's own constraint line in the table create (rather than inline with each column). IMO, that's the preferred approach anyway. I would hope that you name your keys as well.

Comment: @TomH do you think it's even necessary to have `EntryID` in this table? Can I just use the composite key (PersonID, AddressID) and create a linked table with only those two IDs?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have an EntryID. I'm very much not from the camp of, "Every table needs an identity primary key". All it does in this case is allow you to end up with duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LinkedTable] (
    [EntryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [PersonID] [bigint] NOT NULL
    , [AddressID] [int] NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_LinkedTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [EntryID] ASC
    ) WITH (
          PAD_INDEX = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LinkedTable]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LinkedTable]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([AddressID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Address] ([ID])
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LinkedTable] ON [dbo].[LinkedTable] (
      [PersonID] ASC
    , [AddressID] ASC
) WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF
    , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
    , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
    , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
    , DROP_EXISTING = OFF
    , ONLINE = OFF
    , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```